# Parsing numbers from text using Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, text-parsing

I need a regular expression (ideally PHP compatible) that finds all numbers that are preceded by a boundary, equal sign (=), or colon (:), but ignores percentages (digits followed by a % sign), times, dates, and ISO 8859-1 Symbol Entity Numbers (such as `&#160;`).

Have been using the following, but it does not work every time:

```
/(^:|\b|=|^&)([0-9]*[0-9.]*[0-9]+)(^%:;)?
```

Comment: _"but it does not work everytime"_, when does "it" not work? More specifically: what input does it not match, which you want it to match? A list of valid and invalid input would make it easier.

Comment: Also, can you give an example of times and dates that you do not want it to match?

Comment: Are you sure you want to match any number starting with a boundary? This makes it possible for `abc123.5` to get `5` captured since `.` creates a boundary...

Comment: The most complex part of your requirements is ignoring of dates and times. I'd recommend to write an regular expression to remove dates and times from the text (before matching for numbers). Your regexp looks broken to me, but may be that's PHP? I am only familiar with shell and perl and Java REs

Answer (score 1):

Your regexp is seriously broken:

- You seem to be using the caret (^) as "not" -- it has that meaning only inside character classes; elsewhere it means "start of input".
- Your dot should be escaped out or it will match any character.
- A number preceded by an equal sign or a colon always starts at a boundary (as = and : are not \w and numbers are) -- so only the \b is necessary.

I absolutely recommend reading a good Regular Expression reference -- "man perlre" was my source many years ago, but I'm sure there are better ones now.

The following should do what you want, assuming the numbers start AND END on a boundary, don't have thousands separators and use a dot as decimal separator, that times and dates are sequences of numbers separated by ":", "-", or "/", and that such sequences of numbers are times and dates. It should be easy to improve on this if these assumptions are not correct.

```
/\b(?<!&#|\d[:\/-])(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?!%|[:\/-]\d)\b/
```

Explanation:

- (?<! ...) negative look-behind excluding everything you don't want to see BEFORE your numbers.
- (\d+(?:.\d+)?) number with integer and decimal part, capturing only one group
- (?! ...) negative look-ahead excluding everything you don't want to see AFTER your numbers.

Note I'm also assuming that you don't have numbers preceded by "&#" but not followed by ";". Coding your regexp if this assumption doesn't hold is a more difficult problem.

Test:

```
$ pcretest
PCRE version 7.8 2008-09-05

  re> /\b(?<!&#|\d[:\/-])(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?!%|[:\/-]\d)\b/g
data> a12
No match
data> a 12
 0: 12
 1: 12
data> 12-12
No match
data> 12:12
No match
data> 12 23
 0: 12
 1: 12
 0: 23
 1: 23
data> &#12
No match
data> :12
 0: 12
 1: 12
data> =12
 0: 12
 1: 12
data> 12/12
No match
data> 12%
No match
```